# Keep getting TimeoutOverflowWarning number does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer. Timeout duration was set to 1

Tags: javascript, api, http, reddit

I'm using Snoostorm to generate a stream of my reddit inbox. I have two Snoowrap requesters. Both sharing the same clientId, clientSecret, username, and password. I'm not sure if the double requester is what's confusing the program, but after a while I'll get a TimeoutOverflowWarning.

```
// Configuration File for Snoowrap

// Requiring Snoowrap
const Snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
       

// Snoowrap Init
const snoowrap = new Snoowrap({
    userAgent: process.env.USER_AGENT,
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    username: process.env.REDDIT_USER,
    password: process.env.REDDIT_PASS
});

// Snoowrap Config
snoowrap.config({
    requestDelay: 20000,
    warnings: true,
    continueAfterRatelimitError: false,
    retryErrorCodes: [502, 504, 522],
    maxRetryAttempts: 3,
    debug: true
})

module.exports = {
    snoowrap: snoowrap,
    Snoowrap:Snoowrap
}



// Requester file

const snoowrap = require('../config/snoo-config').snoowrap
const Snoowrap = require('../config/snoo-config').Snoowrap
const Snoostorm = require('snoostorm')
const colors = require('colors')

// Need a second client to make requests within the snoostorm, since snoostorm is using the main client to make all the stream requests.
const client = new Snoowrap({
    userAgent: 'process.env.USER_AGENT',
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    username: process.env.REDDIT_USER,
    password: process.env.REDDIT_PASS
})

client.config({
    requestDelay: 20000,
    warnings: true,
    continueAfterRatelimitError: false,
    retryErrorCodes: [502, 504, 522],
    maxRetryAttempts: 3,
    debug: true
})


const follow_ApproveMeThread = function (masterSubName, secondarySubName) {

const inbox = new Snoostorm.InboxStream(client, {
    limit: 5
})

// Get the last 30 comments and a stream of the latest incoming.
inbox.on('item', function (comment) {

    if (comment.subreddit_name_prefixed === `r/${masterSubName}`) {
        author = comment.author.name
        console.log('Adding '.blue + 'u/'.green + author.green + ` as contributor to ${secondarySubName}`.blue)

        snoowrap.getSubreddit(secondarySubName).addContributor({
            name: author
        })

    } else {
        console.log(('u/' + comment.author.name + ' attempted to request me from an unauthorized subreddit!').red)
    }

})
```

}

Then the dump happens:

> [debug] Received a 200 status code from a `get` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/message/inbox?raw_json=1&count=9999&limit=5.
> ratelimitRemaining: 568
>
> Adding u/stickRollBot as contributor to SecondarySub
>
> [debug] Received a 200 status code from a `post` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/r/SecondarySub/api/friend?raw_json=1.
> ratelimitRemaining: 567
>
> [debug] Received a 200 status code from a `get` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/message/inbox?raw_json=1&count=9999&limit=5.
> ratelimitRemaining: 599
>
> [debug] Received a 200 status code from a `get` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/message/inbox?raw_json=1&count=9999&limit=5.
> ratelimitRemaining: 598
>
> [debug] Received a 200 status code from a `get` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/message/inbox?raw_json=1&count=9999&limit=5.
>
> ratelimitRemaining: 597 [debug] Received a 200 status code from a
> `get` request sent to
> https://oauth.reddit.com/message/inbox?raw_json=1&count=9999&limit=5.
> ratelimitRemaining: 596
>
> (node:8728) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2147489113 does not fit into a
> 32-bit signed integer. Timeout duration was set to
>
> 1. (node:8728) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2147509113 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer. Timeout duration was set to 1. (node:8728)
>    TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2147529109 does not fit into a 32-bit signed
>    integer. Timeout duration was set to 1.

And the integer keeps growing and the application continues making sucessfull get requests with status code 200 responses, over and over and depleting the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved it, since It hasn't crashed since, but I removed the limit:5 from the Snoostorm.InboxStream. Apparently It didn't like that I was treating it like a listing?